# Authenticate to multiple gcloud accounts with GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, gcloud

Currently I am connecting to 1 account with the following using GitHub Actions secrets `${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}`:

```
jobs:
  job_id:
    # ...

    steps:
    - uses: 'actions/checkout@v3'

    - id: 'auth'
      name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v0'
      with:
        credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}'
```

I would like to connect with multiple accounts, for example, `$ {{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}` and `${{ secrets.beta_GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}`, is there a way to do that?

Comment: This can be done using [reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows).
Simply create 2 seperate configs and pass secrets for those diffrent accounts you want to use.

Comment: @Michal That sounds promising.. do you have an example?

Comment: All you need is in previously linked docs... but here you have an real world example on video (on AWS) -> [link](https://youtu.be/6vhbFXXXDbI?t=176)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect (I've not tried it!?) you can simply repeat the `google-github-actions/auth` step for each unique Service Account key that you want to use.

If you need to repeat the same steps for various credentials, you can likely use GitHub [matrix](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs).

You **should** try this to prove it to yourself.

The documentation doesn't appear to cover this use-case but, I suspect, the step is equivalent to [`gcloud auth activate-service-account`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account).

If so, then subsequent steps will leverage those credentials (presumably either through `gcloud` or `APPLICATION_DEFAULT_CREDENTIALS`) until changed by e.g `gcloud auth set account ${EMAIL}`

Comment: Using `google-github-actions/auth@v0'` wipes out the previous service account.